# Python - Servidor HTTP y websocket desde cero

Tags: python, http, websocket

Me he propuesto el reto de crear un servidor que maneje tanto HTTP como websockets (en el mismo puerto) en Python usando solamente los sockets de Berkeley.

La parte HTTP funciona muy bien, pero no la parte websocket. Logré realizar el handshaking correctamente, pero no logro hacer que el socket escuche conexiones. Además, los eventos `open` y `close` en el navegador se disparan al mismo tiempo.

Al no haber un `while true` que bloquee asíncronamente el websocket, se alcanzará el último `finally` que lo cierra. Este es el responsable de disparar ambos eventos. He puesto un `time.sleep` de 2 segundos luego del *handshaking* para demostrarlo.

He intentado hacer un `listen` y un `while true` con `accept` como en el socket principal sin éxito.

Lo que necesito es que, por ahora, se dispare el evento `open` en el momento correcto y empiece a escuchar los mensajes enviados por `send` desde el navegador.

Este es el código del servidor (Python):

```
import socket, ssl, threading, hashlib, base64, time
Mimes = {
    'html': 'text/html',
    'css': 'text/css',
    'js': 'text/javascript',
    'png': 'image/png',
    'jpg': 'image/jpg',
    'gif': 'image/gif',
    'svg': 'image/svg+xml',
    'mp3': 'audio/mpeg',
    'mp4': 'video/mp4',
    'ttf': 'font/ttf',
    'rar': 'application/x-rar-compressed',
    'zip': 'application/zip',
    'exe': 'application/x-msdownload',
}

#ManejarCliente
def ManejarCliente (Cliente, Direccion):
    try:
        #Recibiendo mensaje
        Entradas = b''
        while True:
            Parcial = Cliente.recv (4096)
            Entradas += Parcial
            if len (Parcial) < 4096: break
        Entradas = Entradas.split (b'\r\n\r\n') [0].decode ().split ('\r\n')
        URL = Entradas [0].split (' ') [1] [1:] or 'Indice.html'
        Respuesta = []
        try: ClaveWS = next (E for E in Entradas if 'Sec-WebSocket-Key' in E)
        except StopIteration: ClaveWS = None
        #Si existe el header "Sec-WebSocket-Key" entonces es una conexión websocket
        if ClaveWS:
            ClaveWS = ClaveWS.split (': ') [-1].encode () + b'258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11'
            ClaveWS = hashlib.sha1 (ClaveWS).digest ()
            ClaveWS = base64.b64encode (ClaveWS)
            Respuesta.append (b'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching protocol')
            Respuesta.append (b'Upgrade: websocket')
            Respuesta.append (b'Connection: upgrade')
            Respuesta.append (b'Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ' + ClaveWS)
            Respuesta.append (b'')
            Cliente.sendall (b'\r\n'.join (Respuesta))
            #Handshaking exitoso
            time.sleep (2)
            #En este punto "Cliente" debería escuchar mensajes entrantes
        #Si no existe entonces es una conexión http
        else:
            try:
                with open (URL, 'rb') as Lectura: Lectura = Lectura.read ()
                Extension = URL.split ('.') [-1] if '.' in URL else None
                Respuesta.append (b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK')
                Respuesta.append (f"Content-Type: { Mimes [Extension] if Extension in Mimes else 'application/octet-stream' }".encode ())
                Respuesta.append (f"Content-Length: { len (Lectura) }".encode ())
                Respuesta.append (b'')
                Respuesta.append (Lectura)
                Respuesta.append (b'')
            except FileNotFoundError:
                Respuesta.append (b'HTTP/1.1 404 Not found')
                Respuesta.append (b'Content-Type: text/html')
                Respuesta.append (b'')
                Respuesta.append (b'No hay nada')
                Respuesta.append (b'')
            Cliente.sendall (b'\r\n'.join (Respuesta))
    except Exception as Err:
        print (Err)
    finally:
        Cliente.close ()

ContextoSSL = ssl.SSLContext (ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
ContextoSSL.load_cert_chain ('SSL/server.crt', 'SSL/server.key')
PreServidor = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
Servidor = ContextoSSL.wrap_socket (PreServidor)
PreServidor.close ()
Servidor.bind (('0.0.0.0', 443))
Servidor.listen ()
while True:
    try:
        Cliente, Direccion = Servidor.accept ()
        threading.Thread (target = ManejarCliente, args = [Cliente, Direccion [0]]).start ()
    except Exception as Err:
        print (Err)
```

Y este es el código del cliente (Javascript desde el navegador):

```
let WS = new WebSocket ('wss://127.0.0.1')
WS.onopen = function () {
    alert ('Abierto')
    WS.send ('Hola mundo')
}
WS.onclose = function () {
    alert ('Cerrado')
}
WS.onerror = function () {
    alert ('Error')
}
WS.onmessage = function (e) {
    alert (`Mensaje: ${ e.data }`)
}
```